How to load a lua plugin from vimscript (how to call the setup function)
I want to use a neovim plugin that is written in lua (epwalsh/obsidian.nvim for instance).
But my whole config is written in vimscript, and I use the vim-plug package manager.
The problem is that this plugin requires the call of a lua setup function.
Lua package manager (like lazy.nvim) do it fine, but vim-plug doesn't.
How can I properly load the plugin from my vimscript config ?
I tried to execute the file with lua path/to/plugin/init.vim, and to use lua require("plugin-name").setup(), but none of these work.
The plugin I'm trying to load is epwalsh/obsidian.nvim.
